# Consistency for $\bar{X}^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, asymptotics

For a r.s. of size n from Bernoulli population, the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta = p^2$ is $\bar{X}^2 $.

My goal is to prove that this is a consistent estimate of $\theta$ by proving:

- $\lim_{n\to \infty}E(\hat{\theta}) = \theta $
- $\lim_{n\to \infty} V(\hat{\theta})=0$

Focusing on the second case:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}V(\bar{X}^2) = \lim_{n\to \infty}V((\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n})^2)$$

But to prove that this is equal to 0 by the above expansion is cumbersome.

Is there a faster method by which I can show that this variance converges to zero? I know that it is the case that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}V(\bar{X})=0$$

Is there a theorem by which I can apply this result to the variance of my desired estimator?

Comment: Asymptotic variance of $\overline X^2$ can be found using 'delta method'. But it is easier to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem instead.

Comment: @StubbornAtom
So by CMT, If $V(\bar{X}) = \frac{p(1-p)}{n} \implies V(\bar{X}^2) =(\frac{p(1-p)}{n})^2 $

Comment: CMT is not about variance. It directly gives $\overline X \stackrel{P}\to p \implies \overline X^2 \stackrel{P}\to p^2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I see. Given this information, how can I apply it to find the asymptotic variance?